# What does the following line in this bash script do?

Tags: linux, bash

This line is inside my `/etc/rc.sysinit` file on linux:

```
[ -r /proc/mdstat -a -r /dev/md/md-device-map ] && /sbin/mdadm -IRs
```

I'm not so much interested in what it actually accomplishes as opposed to how the syntax works.

Comment: Wouldn't the MAN page be the first place to look?

Comment: @OMGPonies how was I supposed to know that `[` was an alias for `test`

Comment: @OMGPonies: That would normally be a good idea, but `man [` on my nearest Linux system unhelpfully says `No manual entry for [`.

Comment: @GregHewgill: First to `man bash` to learn about your shell's special character replacement, and then do `man \[` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: That doesn't help in this case, there's still no man page.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Strange, my nearest Linux does have that, in section `1`. Oh well.

Comment: @KerrekSB: This happens to be on RHEL 6.2, fwiw.

Comment: Equivalent: `if [ -r "f1" -a -r "f2" ]; then /sbin/...; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tests if the files `/proc/mdstat` and `/dev/md/md-device-map` exists and are readable (`-r`), and if yes executes `/sbin/mdadm -IRs`.

The square brackets are an alternative name of the program `test` (or a Bash replacement thereof), which can test for lots of stuff, such as existence of files. The `-a` is a logical "and".

For more details, see "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" in [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Answer (score 1):

The `[` is actually a command name itself, that is equivalent to the `test` command. So, use `man test` to find out what `-r` means.

Depending on your system, you may find `[` in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37000 Oct  5  2011 /usr/bin/[
```

or it could be a symlink:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4 Oct  5  2011 /usr/bin/[ -> test
```

Some shells also have `[` as a built-in command (and some even have `[[` which provides additional options). As with most built-in commands though, you'll also find an implementation in the filesystem.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:bash], and Bash provides its own implementation of `[`, I believe (as well as providing the more powerful `[[`).

Comment: In *classic* unices, test (and  '[' ) lived in /bin, because /usr was assumed a mountpoint, and the boot process and startup needed test. In modern shells, test is a builtin, of course.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, on FreeBSD the implementation is in `/bin/[`. However, the question specifically mentions Linux.

Comment: As far as I can remember, SysV assumed mountable /usr, too. (and /bin/[ -> /bin/test, which could also have been a hard link). Putting it in /usr/bin is more-or-less an insult, IMHO.

Comment: `[` is *almost* equivalent to `test`. `[` requires a matching `]` as the last argument; `test` doesn't permit it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, you are correct. But that is *only* syntactical; semantically, they are the same. IIRC, `]` pointed to /bin/true .

Comment: @wildplasser: Why would `]` point to `/bin/true`? It's given as a final argument to `[`, not as a command. As for the equivalence, I'd say that `[ ... ]` is equivalent to `test ...` (where the `...` is replaced by some valid expression).

Answer (score 1):

This means :

if `/proc/mdstat` is readable by you and `/dev/md/md-device-map` is readable by you, then run `/sbin/mdadm -IRs`

See `help test`

**NOTE**

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.